# Capture hide event in $modal of angular strap

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-strap

I am using angular Strap to create a modal like :

```
$modal({
  template : "/templ/alert-with-title.html",
  content : content,
  title : title,
  show : true,
  backdrop : true,
  placement : 'center'
});
```

I have the written the following :

```
$scope.$on("modal.hide.before",function() {
  console.log("Closing1");
});
$scope.$on("modal.hide",function() {
  console.log("Closin2");
});
```

My `/templ/alert-with-title.html`  is like this :

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="windowTitleLabel" role="dialog"
    tabindex="-1" class="modal hide fade in modal" id="">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="fui-cross pull-right" ng-click="$hide()"></a>
        <h3 ng-bind="title"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="divDialogElements" >
            <span ng-bind="content"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div>
            <button type="button" ng-click="$hide()"
                class="btn btn-default btn-gray-l gray pull-left mar_t-4">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However even after all this, I get no console logs when i click Ok. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so the solution is very simple, I had to provide the scope to the $modal.

```
$modal({
  template : "/templ/alert-with-title.html",
  content : content,
  title : title,
  show : true,
  backdrop : true,
  placement : 'center',
  scope : $scope
});
```

But what I do not understand that why for an event that is "$emit" , $on of the outside scope would not work

Comment: Thank you!  I've been banging my head on this problem for awhile.  Regarding your question why you need to pass the scope.  I *believe* there is no way for the modal service to broadcast on the local $scope.  One potential solution would to have the modal service broadcast on $rootScope.  I'm not sure if that's the case, but that's my guess.

Answer (score 0):

$emit and $broadcast are angular event handling mechanisms are distinct from events that are found in pure JavaScript. The latter traverse the DOM of your web page. the $event in angular traverses the scope hierarchy present in your module. With that being said here is an excerpt from the source code of angular-strap modal :

```
function ModalFactory(config) {
var $modal = {};
// Common vars
var options = $modal.$options = angular.extend({}, defaults, config);
var promise = $modal.$promise = $bsCompiler.compile(options);
var scope = $modal.$scope = options.scope && options.scope.$new() || $rootScope.$new();
```

the parameters you pass as the argument for your $modal service is the `config` object. the `default` object contains the default values for the parameters. The line of interest is the last line .

There it checks wether you have provided a scope object as one of the parameters. If so then a child of that scope is created via `scope.$new`. Else it creates a scope which is **the child of the top most scope in the heirarchy**.

Therfore **any events which are bubbled up via $emit, from this particular scope can only be caught by the** **$rootScope**.

In the code you posted in the question you did not provide any scope object in the parameters. Hence a child of the `$rootScope` is created, not of the current `$scope` you were working in. In the second code you posted , a child scope of your current `$scope` is created. That is the reason why you are able to handle the 'model.hide' and other events from your current `$scope`

Hope this helps :)